# Converter o resultado timestamp para o formado Data e Hora

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, datetime

Preciso converter o resultado do timestamp (ex.: 121242343543) para o formato `2018-11-09T16:36:01`.

Controller.js:

```
function salvar() {

    var dataBase = new Date().getTime();

    // salva no banco
    var simulacao = {
        cpfCnpj : vm.cpfcnpj,                   
        dataBase : dataBase             
    };

    LaminaService.save(simulacao).then(function() {
        vm.lamina.sucesso = vm.messageService.getA('MA005');
    });

}
```

Na entidade `Simulacao.java`:

```
@Column(name = Constants.TS_SIMULACAO, nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime dataBase;
```

Comment: Use o `momentjs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O construtor do [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) pode receber um timestamp, depois basta extrair as informações que você quiser para uma string ou os métodos prontos como o [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

Exemplo:

```js
let timestamp = 1544380561000; // 09/12/2018 18:36:01
let data = new Date(timestamp);

console.log(data.toISOString());
```

Comment: O detalhe é que `toISOString()` retorna a data/hora em UTC, e para mim não ficou claro se é exatamente isso que o AP precisa. Eu detalho isso na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/342478/112052) (infelizmente não consegui dar mais detalhes por não saber como o Angular lida com datas)

Comment: No meu caso era só uma dica do que pode ser feito, ele pode extrair as informações que precisar do objeto Date. O toISOString foi só um exemplo. Não tive a intenção de entrar em timezone nem nada do tipo. Sua resposta é mais completa do que eu tive a intenção na minha. :)

Comment: Ah sim, eu não quis dizer que sua resposta está errada. Ela faz o que foi perguntado (converter timestamp para formato ISO), tanto que dei +1 :) Só achei que valia a pena detalhar mais (e acabei com uma resposta gigante... ) :)

Comment: Eu até ia detalhar, mas sua resposta já está muito boa. Vou deixar a minha para os preguiçosos. Hahahaha

Comment: @fernandosavio, a solução funcionou perfeitamente. Fiz apenas o incremento do hkotsubo, onde coloquei (data.toISOString().replace(/\.\d{3}Z$/, '')) fechando nos segundos (2018-11-12T12:09:23). Obrigado a todos!

Comment: @hkotsubo, obrigado pelo suporte. Implementei a solução inicial do Fernando incrementando a sua sugestão (data.toISOString().replace(/\.\d{3}Z$/, '')). Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Vi que sua classe Java está usando um [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), então há alguns detalhes a se atentar, **antes de sair fazendo qualquer conversão que seja**. <sup><sub>*Já adianto que não sei os detalhes de como o Angular funciona, mas achei pertinente explicar um pouco sobre datas e timestamps, para que você saiba o que está fazendo quando for converter a data.*</sub></sup>

Um timestamp é um número que representa o tempo decorrido a partir do [*Unix Epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Basicamente, define-se o Unix Epoch como sendo o "Instante Zero", e o timestamp nada mais é do que uma quantidade de tempo que decorrida depois (ou antes) dele.

O valor do Unix Epoch é `1970-01-01T00:00Z` (1 de janeiro de 1970, meia-noite, [em **UTC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)). Detalhe para o `Z` no final, que [indica que a data/hora está em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)). Muitos ignoram este "Z" ou acham que ele não é importante, mas ele faz toda a diferença (com ele, sabemos que a data/hora está em UTC, sem ele, não temos como afirmar nada - a menos que haja algum contexto adicional).

Já o valor do timestamp é geralmente a quantidade de segundos ou milissegundos (também conhecido como "milésimos de segundo"), varia conforme a implementação/linguagem/API. Como você usou o `new Date().getTime()` do JavaScript, [o valor retornado é a quantidade de **milissegundos**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime#Return_value).

Pois bem, o detalhe do timestamp é que **ele é o mesmo no mundo todo**. No momento em que escrevo esta resposta, o timestamp retornado foi `1541808475424` (ou seja 1.541.808.475.424 milissegundos depois do Unix Epoch). Este valor é o mesmo em qualquer lugar do mundo: qualquer computador que tivesse obtido o valor do timestamp no mesmo instante que eu, não importa onde esteja, teria como resultado o mesmo valor. Portanto, o timestamp representa um ponto específico na linha do tempo, um único instante.

Só que este mesmo valor de timestamp pode significar uma data e hora diferente, dependendo do fuso-horário usado. No caso, o timestamp `1541808475424` pode corresponder aos seguintes dias e horários:

- Em São Paulo: 9 de novembro de 2018, 22:07:55.424 (dez da noite do dia 9)
- Em Los Angeles: 9 de novembro de 2018, 16:07:55.424 (4 da tarde do dia 9)
- Em Berlim: **10** de novembro de 2018, 01:07:55.424 (uma da manhã do dia 10)
- Em UTC: 10 de novembro de 2018, 00:07:55.424 (meia-noite do dia 10)

Ou seja, o mesmo valor de timestamp pode corresponder a uma data e hora diferentes, dependendo do *timezone* (fuso horário) que você usar como referência. Faz sentido, pois agora, neste exato momento, em cada parte do mundo, o dia de hoje e a hora atual não são necessariamente os mesmos daqui (a velha história do "Já é Ano-Novo na Austrália", ou ainda "Sempre é happy-hour em algum do mundo").

---

#### Por que estou dizendo tudo isso?

Porque no Java a classe `LocalDateTime` possui os campos de data e hora (dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto, segundo e frações de segundo), mas **não possui nenhuma informação sobre o timezone**.

Se eu crio um `LocalDateTime` qualquer:

```
// 9 de novembro de 2018, 10:30 da manhã
LocalDateTime dataHora = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 11, 9, 10, 30);
```

Este `LocalDateTime` representa "9 de novembro de 2018, 10:30 da manhã". Mas esta classe não sabe em qual timezone ela está, então ela não pode ser mapeada para um único valor de timestamp. "9 de novembro de 2018, 10:30 da manhã" em São Paulo aconteceu em um instante diferente de "9 de novembro de 2018, 10:30 da manhã" em Berlim. Dependendo do timezone escolhido, este `LocalDateTime` vai resultar em um timestamp diferente.

Então a conversão de timestamp para data/hora não é tão simples assim. Você precisa definir qual timezone será usado.

Pelo que entendi, você está criando a variável `dataBase` no JavaScript e passando para o Java. Você disse que a variável precisa estar no [formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) (é o nome do formato que você pediu: `2018-11-09T16:36:01`). E como você quer a data atual, basta usar `new Date()`. Não precisa chamar `getTime()` para obter o timestamp, para depois obter o `Date` de novo. Use o `Date` diretamente e o método `toISOString()`, que retorna a data no formato desejado:

```js
// data atual
let data = new Date();
console.log(data.toISOString());
```

Se precisar mesmo criar um `Date` a partir do timestamp, faça `new Date(timestamp)` como [sugeriu o @fernandosavio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/342425/112052).

O detalhe é que `toISOString()` [retorna o valor do timestamp convertido para UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString#Return_value) (além de retornar a fração de segundos, que você disse que não precisa). Ou seja, a data e hora estarão em UTC (que pode não ser o fuso horário que você precisa), e além disso terá o `Z` no final (e aí eu não sei o que você está usando exatamente para transformar esta string para um `LocalDateTime`, então pode ser que isso cause algum problema na conversão).

Claro que você pode remover o `Z` do jeito "feio" (`data.toISOString().replace('Z', '')`), e que eu particularmente não gosto, pois remove uma informação importante. Saber que a data/hora está em UTC nos dá confiança para convertê-la para o valor correto do timestamp. Se eu não sei que aquela data/hora está em UTC, ela pode estar em qualquer timezone, e portanto pode corresponder a vários valores diferentes de timestamp. Mas se não tiver jeito, remova o Z e tente contornar o problema na outra ponta...

Outro detalhe é que `toISOString()` também retorna a fração de segundos. Se quiser removê-la juntamente com o "Z", pode fazer `data.toISOString().replace(/\.\d{3}Z$/, '')`.

---

Outra alternativa em JavaScript é usar a biblioteca [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), juntamente com o [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) (uma extensão para trabalhar com timezones). Com isso você pode obter a data/hora atual em um timezone específico:

```js
// data/hora atual no timezone de São Paulo
let now = moment().tz("America/Sao_Paulo")
// formato ISO 8601
console.log(now.format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss'));

// usando um valor de timestamp e convertendo para o timezone de São Paulo
let dt = moment.tz(1541808475424, "America/Sao_Paulo")
// formato ISO 8601
console.log(dt.format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Com isso, os valores de data e hora serão convertidos para o timezone que você precisar. Se quiser retornar também as frações de segundo, mude o formato para `YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

Os nomes dos timezones seguem o formato "Continente/Região" (como `America/Sao_Paulo`, `Europe/Berlin` etc) conforme definição da [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). Para saber todos os timezones disponíveis, basta usar `moment.tz.names()`.

Desta forma você controla exatamente o timezone que será usado e passa os valores corretos de data e hora no parâmetro.

---

Como já disse no início, eu não sei os detalhes de como o Angular funciona, nem como a string criada no JavaScript será convertida para `LocalDateTime`. De qualquer forma, para converter um timestamp para uma data/hora específica você precisa ter em mente todos os detalhes acima.

Muitas linguagens e APIs escondem essa complexidade simplesmente escolhendo algum timezone "padrão" por debaixo dos panos, e aí você acaba com datas e/ou horas "erradas" sem saber o motivo. Usar as ferramentas adequadas (nesse caso, uma lib especializada) permite ter maior controle sobre os timezones usados e ter menos surpresas ao trabalhar com as datas.

*Se eu encontrar mais detalhes sobre como o Angular lida com datas, eu atualizo a resposta.*